# Qt Creator won't recognize any Qt version

Tags: 11.10, qt-creator

I've just installed Qt Creator from the Ubuntu Software Center.

When I try to open any project other than a Qt Quick project I get following error message:

> **No valid qt versions found.**
>   Please add a qt version in Tools/Options or via the maintenance tool of the SDK.

In Tools → Options → Qt4, `qmake-qt4` was added to the list automatically.

This is what my Qt4 options menu looks like.

[image: qt-creator options menu]

Here is the [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/763145/) of `dpkg --get-selection | grep qt`.

What am I missing to get Qt Creator to let me open Qt C++ projects?

Comment: Add the name of the packages that you have installed check if you have qt-maker, designer, creator.

Comment: I have `designer`, `qtcreator` and `qmake-qt4`.

Comment: Please provide the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep qt`.

Comment: You should also check for `libqt4-dev`.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Added the requested information to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem wasn't the missing Qt version but the missing tool chain.

In `Tools → Options → Tool Chains` add GCC and set your gcc path as the *Compiler path*.

Answer (score 5):

I thought the qtCreator package would install g++, make, etc., but it doesn't.
Install `build-essential` to solve it :).

Answer (score 2):

As to me, it looks perfectly fine. My *Qt versions* tab in options dialog looks identically.
The only thing that comes into my mind, is that Qt version is saved per-project, which means that you need to change *Build Settings* in *Projects* tab by explicitly selecting *Default Qt Version*.

Comment: Don't judge hard, I might be wrong :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've posted an answer with the solution.

Comment: Hmm.. Why the hell you don't have gcc in your PATH? :)

Comment: Well I don't know why it couldn't find it since `/usr/bin` is definitely in my `PATH` and `gcc` is in there.