# No valid kits found, although a kit exists

Tags: qt

I'm trying to open a new project in Qt Creator, and I'm getting a **"No valid kits found"** error. In options I do see a kit configured.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26513032/900394) and installed gcc from the maintaiance tool (although I already had it installed), but I'm still having the same problem. I think I need to choose that gcc I downloaded in `Options > Compilers`, but I can't find it (although it installed successfully). I searched in `/home/user/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/` - there's a `bin` folder, but no `gcc` file inside.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/89092/287729) also didn't help.

Screenshots of my Qt Options:

[image: Kits]

[image: Qt_Versions]

[image: Compilers]

[image: Debuggers]

[image: kits]

[image: QT_Versions]

[image: Compilers]

[image: Debuggers]

Here's what I'm getting:

[image: no_valid_kits]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. To solve it do these steps: go to Tools->Options->Qt Versions->add. Here you add the qmake. 
[image]

After that go to Kits tab, select Desktop default and than in option Qt version select/set your qt version.

Now if you try to create a project the kit will be there :)

Comment: thank you very much